# Runnable .jar or.exe file doesn't run correctly

Tags: java, jar, executable

I've created the application in java-eclipse that when pressing a random key on a keyboard it prints random .pdf file with a printer. The application work well when i run it in eclipse, but when i create a runnable .jar file it runs the application (GUI) but when i press the key it doesn't print anything. If I press random keys several times, it prints...

I used also the Launch4J to create executable file, but it's also the problem that when i press the key it doesn't print anything.

For the project I used .jar library for printing .pdf-s.

What's the problem?

Comment: With that much information, it is really hard to say. Do you have any error ,message or is everything exactly same as running from eclipse when you run program from jar file

Comment: Try opening the compiled file in a decompiler such as JD-GUI and seeing if the code looks the same.  Can't really think of anything else with so little info

Comment: When I create runnable .jar with Eclipse I get 2 warnings:
-one is for the licenses - review the licenses associated with libraries. I think it's because I'm using the library for printing pdf-s. 
-the second warning - JAR export finished with warnings. see details   for additional details: 
 Example: Exported with compile warnings: Printer/src/PDF/PrinterZaPDF.java

Comment: With JD-GUI the code seems pretty the same..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of information you need but i will try to be more specific..
I have a project that has three classes - Graphics.java, Logic.java and Runnable.java. It uses external .jar library for printing pdf-s. And in a project i also have 46 .pdf documents that the program picks up randomly and print it when any key is pressed. Here is the description, how i do the runnable .jar file:
http://shrani.si/f/34/He/14Tn9ZWq/description.jpg

Here is also the code of the KeyEventDispatcher:

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
          .addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
              @Override
              public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {

                  if(e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED){
                      if(print == true){  
                          pzp.printaj(); //This is the object to the Logic.java where he calls the method print();
                          print = false;

                      }
                  }

                  if(e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED){
                      print = true;

                  }

                  return false;
              }});
```

Don't forget, If i run the application in eclipse it works!

Comment: Ok, I found something new! 
The whole logical part is in a try-catch block and if it doesn't run in try then system.out.println("Unsuccesfull");. I tried to run the .jar from cmd and when i press any key i get Unsuccesfull message in console. There must be a problem with the code or with the license of external .jar library.